# AWS Elasticbeanstalk overriding Nginx config using .platform is not working

Tags: laravel, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying my Laravel application to AWS ElasticBeanstalk. I have deployed it. Now, I am trying to override "/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/php.conf" file using .platform folder.

I created .platform/etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/php.conf file right inside the project's root folder. Then I put in the configuration content.

Then I deploy my application executing "be deploy" command. But the Nginx config file is not overridden. What is wrong with my config and how can I get it working?

I tried using .ebextensions too creating a config file with the following content. The file is not just created.

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/laravel.conf:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            gzip_static on;
      }
```

Comment: Did the solution provided here work for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `nginx` config file you are trying to set is used in **Amazon Linux 1** (AL1).

For AL2, the `nginx` config files should be provided ([aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html)) using:

- `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`

or if you want to overwrite main `nginx` config file, use

- `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf`

Thus, you can try the following file `.platform/nginx/conf.d/laravel.conf` with content of:

```
location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
      gzip_static on;
}
```

If it does not work, you can inspect nginx logs in `/var/log` or nginx config folder to check if the file is correctly placed in nginx config folder.

> ```
> Solution I used
> ```

I used this and it worked.
`.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/laravel.conf`

Comment: @dryleaf You can make new question with details of your EB setup and any relevant error messages.

Comment: this does not work for me. I've created a file in my app root dir: .platform/nginx/nginx.conf with the context copied from AWS /etc/nginx/nginx.conf plus added `client_max_body_size 500M;`

I do not see any error in `/var/log/eb-engine.log`

However when deployment is done there is not client_max_body_size property set in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: @aldm So why not make a question specific to your use-case?

Comment: I just edited the question, sorry it went to early :)

Comment: I temporarily solve it by adding client_max_body_size to `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/config/private/nginx/nginx.conf.template` but this won't work for all environments, so it would be better if I can make .platforms/nginx/nginx.conf works :)

Comment: Sorry my fault :)
By default all dirs starting with . were exclude from app bundle, meaning that .platform and even .ebextensions dirs were not at all added to app bundle. I needed to change zip command in my GitHub Action for deploying to AWS to this:
`zip deploy.zip -r * .[^.]* --exclude=**node_modules** --exclude=**postmarket_medias**`